# Best way to generate, and then open a URL using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to open a webpage on a new window buy building a URL based off of a users input. The issue im running into is that it will open a new window, but will not use the generated URL. It will open an about:blank window instead.

I put the code in JSFIDDLE, and it actually works there, but I can't figure out why its not working on  my page. But JSFIDDLE actually leaves the original page saying [Object], which I can't figure out either.

Any help is appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/cmirab/SHFgw/2/

HTML:

```
 <form id="search" name="Safe">
    <h1>How Safe</h1>
    <h2>is your Neighborhood?</h2>
    <p class="p1">Enter your zip to find crime statistics in your area:</p>
    <input type="text" name="search">
    <input type="hidden" name="url" id="url">
    <a class="button1" href="javascript:window.open(document.Safe.url.value)">Search</a>
    </form>
```

JQuery
    var partFields = $('#search').val('#search').not('#url');

```
$(partFields).change(function() {
var urlB = 'http://classic.crimereports.com/map?';
var urlE = '&searchButton.x=0&searchButton.y=0';
var urlValue = urlB + partFields.serialize() + urlE;

$('#url').val(urlValue); // set the hidden input value
});
```

CSS:

```
 #search {background:#232426;padding:5px 0 21px 24px;color:#737985;margin:0 0 30px;line height:15px;}
    #search h1 {font-size:71px;line-height:1.2em;color:#ffad01;letter-spacing:-4px;}
    #search h2 {font-size:35px;letter-spacing:-1px;margin:0 0 10px;}
    #search input {border:none;background:#37383a;padding:9px 10px;margin:0 4px 0 0;width:240px;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead, I modified some of your js and markup as well.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SHFgw/3/)

```
var $searchbox = $('#search input[name="search"]')
    $searchbox.change(function() {
    var urlB = 'http://classic.crimereports.com/map?';
    var urlE = '&searchButton.x=0&searchButton.y=0';
    var urlValue = urlB + $searchbox.serialize() + urlE;

    $('.button1').attr('href',urlValue); // set the hidden input value
});​


<form id="search" name="Safe" >
                    <h1>How Safe</h1>
                    <h2>is your Neighborhood?</h2>
                    <p class="p1">Enter your zip to find crime statistics in your area:</p>
                    <input type="text" name="search">
                    <input type="hidden" name="url" id="url">
                    <a class="button1" href="javascript:window.open(document.Safe.url.value)" target="_blank">Search</a>
                </form>​
```

Comment: This definately made it better, but now im just getting a popup that has javascript:window.open(document.Safe.url.value) as the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the script after the html form, because when the script runs it searches for the element with id "search" which is currently not present there, hence the value of the input fields which are not present there is returned as an empty string.